# Maven project use multiple GitLab Package Registry

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab, registry

I am trying to setup 2 GitLab projects (project a & project b) as the remote maven repository for my other project (project c) using GitLab Maven Package Registry.

Now I have 2 GitLab Maven Package Registry

- project A -> id : 112233
- project B -> id : 445566

So, now I need to set the registry setup in my project C pom.xml file

How I can do that, because we can't have multiple  in our pom.xml file

```
<!--registry setup for project a-->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/112233/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/112233/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/112233/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<!--registry setup for project b-->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/445566/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/445566/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/445566/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Better use a repository manager it's easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If project A and B sit in the same group, then you shall use the [group-level Maven endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#group-level-maven-endpoint) in project C's `pom.xml`:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Else, I guess you should be able to specify one repository for each:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven-a</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/112233/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven-b</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/445566/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

/!\ Don't forget to set your [Maven authentication credentials](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-to-the-package-registry-with-maven) in your `settings.xml` file in either case (unless your project has public visibility).
Prefer using the [CI_JOB_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-with-a-ci-job-token-in-maven).